# Terraform nested maps for_each

Tags: terraform

I have created this terraform variable.

```
variable "test" {
  default = {
    map1 = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "user"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting4"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting100" = "123|456|789"
      }
    }
    map2 = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "user2"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "100500|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|100500"
        "setting4"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting100" = "100500|456|789"
      }
    }
    mapN = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "userN"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "100500|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|100500"
        "setting4"   = "123|100500|789"
        "settingN" = "100500|456|789"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this variable could be a huge amount of maps like `map1, map2, mapN`
Also, there are could be a lot of "settings" with different names like `setting1, setting2, dasdasd_23123, asdqw22_qq`, but value always would have three elements `"123|456|789"`.

I try to pass values to a module like:

```
module "test" {
  source = "./test"

  for_each = var.test

  map_name = each.key
  name1    = element(split("|", each.value.config), 0)
  name2    = element(split("|", each.value.config), 2)
  name3    = element(split("|", each.value.config), 1)
}
```

Is it possible to use `for_each` in `for_each`?
Does any have such a kind of experience?
Could anyone share examples?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "test" {
  default = {
    map1 = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "user"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting4"   = "123|456|789"
        "setting100" = "123|456|789"
      }
    }
    map2 = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "user2"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "100500|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|100500"
        "setting4"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting100" = "100500|456|789"
      }
    }
    mapN = {
      secrets = {
        "user" = "userN"
        "pass" = "123456"
      }
      config = {
        "setting1"   = "100500|456|789"
        "setting2"   = "123|100500|789"
        "setting3"   = "123|456|100500"
        "setting4"   = "123|100500|789"
        "settingN" = "100500|456|789"
      }
    }
  }
}

variable "flattened_test" {
  default = [
    for map_name, map_data in var.test :
    {
      map_name = map_name
      secrets  = map_data.secrets
      config   = {
        for setting_name, setting_value in map_data.config :
        "${setting_name}_value" => setting_value
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
module "test" {
  source = "./test"

  for_each = { for item in var.flattened_test : item.map_name => item }

  map_name = each.key
  name1    = element(split("|", each.value.config.setting1_value), 0)
  name2    = element(split("|", each.value.config.setting1_value), 2)
  name3    = element(split("|", each.value.config.setting1_value), 1)
}
```

In the locals block, we create a new local variable top_level_map_names that contains the list of all top-level map names (map1, map2, mapN).

Then, in the module block, we use a nested for_each loop:

The outer loop iterates over the top-level map names (local.top_level_map_names).
The inner loop iterates over the nested maps (secrets and config) within each top-level map.